# Getting Http "ERROR 500" with symfony4 using byethost

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, upload, symfony4

I have uploaded the project in the server, but when i go to the link of my site `url.com/public/index.php` i see this error **HTTP ERROR 500**.

I have make a clear to cache and same problem
Any suggestion to solve this problem? CAN I disable the putenv() in symfony?

after displaying error, i see this message :

> Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   /home/vol15_7/byethost8.com/b8_23863116/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php
>   on line 130

Comment: Can i disable it in symfony?

Comment: Instead of commenting to your own question, you can edit it to add (additional) questions.

Answer (score 3):

The `putenv` function is forbidden on your server. Your hosting provider has certainly forbidden the usage of this function which is used by `DotEnv` component.

Try to use another method to set environment variable like described in Symfony documentation about [server configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html).

Comment: If i remove The Dotenv Component ?

Comment: You should test it, it could be an answer to your problem, but you certainly have to update your application to initialize env data without using `.env` file.

Comment: can you give me steps to do? what i do now ? remove dotenv or require symfony/apache-pack, because i haven't understand anything :(

Comment: Nobody can do it, because we do not have any information about your hosting server. You should validate this answer for avoid time loosing to communauty. Then, you should contact your hoster because symfony is certainly already deployed by another customer. On your server, you can do some tests too to discover what is authorized, what is forbidden. After these steps, if you have a more concrete question, you can ask it on Stackoverflow. But currently, your question is too broad :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this issue on some hosting without the possibility to enable dotenv.
Symfony provides a way to dump .env variables into a PHP file. This way it won't try to use dotenv at all.

All you need to do is to run `composer dump-env prod`

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-production